# tab, listview and intent

Tags: android, listview, tabs, android-intent

I have three 2 tab TabA and TabB. TabA displays value its ok. Now in Tab2 i have listview displaying the values. Whenever I click the listitem value that value have to pass to the next activity and new tab have to be created based on that value every time I click the listItem the tab should be generated. My problem is inside the click event of listitem  intent = new Intent() is not supported. My code is as follows

```
public class FriendLists extends TabActivity {
       //Declarations

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.friendtab);

        connection=XMPPLogic.getInstance().getConnection();
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

            lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.footerlist);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listitems,R.id.list_content, my_own_listarray);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //end of listing friends
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id){
      //problem is here when i try to put intent and pass String S it creates a problem                     
                String S=group.get(position).toString();

//              spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(S).setIndicator(S,
//                        res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_friendlist))
//                    .setContent(null);
//              tabHost.addTab(spec);

                // set the message to display
                alertbox.setMessage(S).show();  

            }});

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this,Friends.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("friendlist").setIndicator("Friend List",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_friendlist))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("onlinefriends").setIndicator("Online Friends",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_friendlist))
                .setContent(R.id.footerlist));
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not supported"? It doesnt compile or does it generate an exception?

Comment: The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<Classname>) is undefined...this is the message displayed when i declared intent=new Intent(this,destination.class)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From inside an anonymous inner class, you cannot refer to a non-final local variable (`intent`) that was declared outside of it.

I assume you just need a temporary variable to hold the intent you want to pass to `setContent`. Just declare it inside `onItemClick`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( /* do your thing */ );
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(S).setIndicator(S,
           res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_friendlist))
       .setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: thanks for the response but i tried this but creates a problem...The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<Classname>) is undefined

Comment: Check out the [constructors of `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent()). You are passing unsupported arguments.